# GAWK premature EOF with getline

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

Here's the deal: I need to read a *specific amount of bytes*, which will be processed later on. I've encountered a strange phenomenon though, and I couldn't wrap my head around it. Maybe someone else? :)

*NOTE: The following code-examples are slimmed-down versions just to show the effect!*

A way of doing this, at least with `gawk`, is to set `RS` to a catch-all *regex*, and then use `RT` to see, what has been matched:

```
RS="[\x00-\xFF]"
```

Then, quite simply use the following *awk-script*:

```
BEGIN {
  ORS=""
  OFS=""
  RS="[\x00-\xFF]"
}
{
  print RT
}
```

This is working fine:

```
$ echo "abcdef" | awk -f bug.awk
abcdef
```

However, I'll need several files, to be accessed, so I am forced to use `getline`:

```
BEGIN {
  ORS=""
  OFS=""
  RS="[\x00-\xFF]"

  while (getline)
  {
    print RT
  }
}
```

This is *seemingly* equivalent to the above, but when running it, there is a nasty surprise:

```
$ echo "abcdef" | awk -f bug.awk
abc
```

This means, for some reason, `getline` is encountering the EOF condition *3 bytes early*. So, did I miss something, that I should know about the internals of *bash/Linux* buffering, or did I find a dreadful **bug**?

Just for the record: I am using GNU Awk 4.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Linux 3.13.0/36)

Any tips, guys?

UPDATE: I am using `getline`, because I have previously read and preprocessed the file(s), and stored in file(s) `/dev/shm/`. Then I'd need to do a few final processing steps. The above examples are just bare minimum scripts, to show the problem.

Comment: I don't have a way to test this right now, but I would expect `awk` to honor a list of files from the cmd-line without need for getline. Did you try your original code with multiple files? pluse-uno for well researched problem. But yes, your test seems like it should work, and not obvious why you're losing data. Oh.. any chance of `\r\n` line endings in your data? If so, `dos2unix file` or `... | tr -d '\015' | ...`. Keep posting and Good Luck.

Comment: Well, what I am doing, is reading in from `stdin`, and putting it in a temporary file in `/dev/shm`, and then reading that file back, and doing some processing. (The data should come from the network via `nc`) 
And thanks a lot, I'm trying my best... ;)

Comment: Hm.. you said "However, I'll need several files, to be accessed, .." . For other readers, you may want to clarify that your `echo abcedfg | awk ..` relfects how you really want to deal with this problem. Good luck!

Comment: For fun maybe try putting a `print ""` after the `while` loop --- in case there's some lingering output that's not getting flushed for some reason.

Comment: `I'll need several files, to be accessed, so I am forced to use getline` - that statement is completely unclear since awk doesn't require getline when reading multiple files and it gets even less clear once you tell us you're reading from `stdin` not from any files. Please edit your question to clearly state where awk is getting it's input from and, if you think you need to use `getline` then clearly state why that is the case. You might also want to read http://awk.info/?tip/getline.

Comment: There are several tools which will read a specified number of bytes. `head` is probably the simplest but `dd` is more flexible. `awk` is probably not the simplest choice.

Comment: Make that http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline instead of awk.info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is a manifestation of the bug reported [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2014-05/msg00000.html), which (if I understand it correctly) has the effect of terminating the `getline` prematurely when close to the end of input, rather than at the end of input.

The bug fixes seem to have been committed on [May 9](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/commit/io.c?id=40694fc1c11bae6fac8e809a6a4c161c12cc37b7) and [May 10](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/commit/io.c?id=0ebae58196378b06e083109701875f15c60a7b9a), 2014, so if you can upgrade to version 4.1 it should fix the problem.

---

If all you need to do is read a specified number of bytes, I'd suggest that `awk` is not the ideal tool, regardless of bugs. Instead, you might consider one of the following two standard utilities, which will be able to do the work rather more efficiently:

```
head -c $count
```

or

```
dd bs=$count count=1
```

With `dd` you can explicitly set the input file (`if=PATH`) and output file (`of=PATH`) if stdin/stdout are not appropriate. With `head` you can specify the input file as a positional parameter, but the output always goes to stdout.

See [`man head`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/head.1.html) and [`man dd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html) for more details.

Comment: Well, then I did hit a **bug**. I'm not asking, how you've known about this. :) You're right, `awk` is probably not the right tool for this. But the thing is, I have to process line based data, with occasional blocks of octets in there, so it was rather tempting to try and get away with this. But I didn't. :)

Comment: @Dan: I didn't know, but I verified that it happens on v4.0 and not v4.1, since I have both available. Then I searched the buglist for getline, which made it pretty easy to find. Good luck with the project.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, using GNU Awk 4.1.3 (on a Mac), your program with getline works as expected:

```
echo "abcdef" | gawk 'BEGIN{ORS="";OFS="";RS="[\x00-\xFF]";
  while (getline) {print RT}}'
abcdef
$ gawk --version
GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1
```

Comment: That will spin off into an infinite loop if the `getline` fails. See http://awk.info/?tip/getline.

Comment: Just for the record, according to the [official doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline.html) it shouldn't: `[...] The getline command returns 1 if it finds a record and 0 if it encounters the end of the file. [...]`

Comment: @Dan: you left out the next sentence: "If there is some error... getline returns -1". -1, like 1, is true.